# Formatting a float value

Tags: mysql, number-formatting

I am fetching data from MySQL using PHP. I know that most values stored in the database are float. Sometimes, the database outputs values like `3.9999E-5` and sometimes like `0.00104961904762` (14 digits).

How can I truncate the value to 8 digits only. I am currently using:

```
<? echo sprintf("%.8f",$get_results['Price']);?>
```

Comment: I think this question is more suitable for http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post question even though I have 70+ reputation and many badges

Comment: What datatype are you using to store the numbers?

Comment: I am using text as data type

Comment: You have already posted two questions at stackoverflow. So why do you think that you are not allowd to post questions at stackoverflow?

Comment: it seems that I upvoted yout question accidentally some minutes ago

Answer (score 1):

You need MySQL's [**FORMAT function**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format)

To round 0.00000123456 to 8 places, run the following within PHP:

```
mysql> select FORMAT(0.00000123456,8);
+-------------------------+
| FORMAT(0.00000123456,8) |
+-------------------------+
| 0.00000123              |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

**Give it a Try !!!**